# Trying to unmarshal data into interface in golang

Tags: go

Trying to unmarshal data into interface. It is working fine. But If i access res.page or res.Page not working

I got the below error:

```
res.Page undefined (type interface {} is interface with no methods)
```

Below is my code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var res interface{}
    str := `{"page": 1, "fruits": ["apple", "peach"]}`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(res.Page)
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to use type assertion.

Comment: Read the [docs on unmarshaling](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshal) mainly the rules specified after the line *"To unmarshal JSON into an interface value, Unmarshal stores one of these in the interface value:"*. Here's an example of type assertion: https://play.golang.org/p/kC1OPzLewS_6

Comment: You say it's not working, but you don't say what error you get. What is the error? It probably gives you a clue as to how to fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**interface{}** specifies zero methods (and ofc zero fields).
What you need is a **map[string]interface{}**

Try this https://play.golang.org/p/WBwXKob4zdA

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var res map[string]interface{}
    str := `{"page": 1, "fruits": ["apple", "peach"]}`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(str), &res)
    fmt.Println(res["page"])
}
```

You may want to check:

- https://tour.golang.org/methods/14
- https://tour.golang.org/methods/15

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But If i need unmarshal array for example `str := `[{"page": 1, "fruits": ["apple", "peach"]}]`` In this case how it work?

Comment: @Testadmin https://play.golang.org/p/RcDy2uSZf5Y better to define a new type.
Although Go has something "dynamic" like empty interface, it a type-safe language.